# Django Admin upload image with foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have a model `Product` with a `User` and `ProductImages` as foreign key.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...


class ProductImages(models.Model):
    image_type = models.CharField(max_length=33,default='image_type')    
    image_file = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default='magickhat-profile.jpg'
    )


class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    productimages = models.ForeignKey(ProductImages, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='product_title')    
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='product_description')    
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    product_view = models.IntegerField(default=0) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_change', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

forms.py

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):

    productimages = forms.ImageField()
     
    CHOICES_STATUS = (('Pronto', 'Pronto'),('Em obras', 'Em obras'),('Lançamento', 'Lançamento'),)
    product_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES_STATUS)
    product_title = forms.CharField()    
    product_description = forms.CharField()  
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

admin.py

```
class AdminProductModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(user_id=request.user)

kadmin.register(User, UserAdmin)
kadmin.register(Product, AdminProductModel)
```

But in the admin `Product` model the field for image is redering as `select field` no `ImageField`

My purpose is add a `upload image field` on django model administration.

If i use `ImageField` direct on `Product` model the field is redering ok, but i need a external table to store that image becouse is a multimage upload, so i need a foreing key.

How is the right way to that purpose.

I see other questions about that, but the majority is old versions, and is not for custom `AdminSite`, like me.

Django 3.2 version Class View Based

As suggested in comments i change the relationship between models like:

**uptade**

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='product_title')    
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='product_description')    
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    product_view = models.IntegerField(default=0) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_change', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class ProductImages(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_type = models.CharField(max_length=33,default='image_type')    
    image_file = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default='magickhat-profile.jpg'
    )
```

forms.py

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):

    image_file = forms.ImageField()

    CHOICES_STATUS = (('Pronto', 'Pronto'),('Em obras', 'Em obras'),('Lançamento', 'Lançamento'),)
    product_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES_STATUS)
    product_title = forms.CharField()    
    product_description = forms.CharField()  

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

My question now is, how bring that field `image_file` from `ProducImages` to `ProductForm`?

Comment: django is doing what you wrote. ```productimages``` is a foreign key, not a ImageField so it ll refrence to ProductImage instance only.

Comment: if it's a multi-image upload as you stated, the foreign key won't work. In that case, your image model should have a foreign key to the product model

Comment: @shivankgtm @Eternal, ok i change the relationship between models, now how i can render that field on `Product` form?  How bring tha field from external model?

Answer (score 0):

Am guessing you want to be able to post multiple images to your database in that case you should use StackedInline to merge the two models together then you can have multiple fields in the database to upload more images. You do that through the admin.py like so:

```
class ProductImagesAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
       model = ProductImages

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      # The field your want to display 
      list_display  = ['','']
      # Here you link the models together 
      inlines = [ ProductImagesAdmin]
```

To upload multiple images from the frontend you will need a form to handle

```
class ProductImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
        model = ProductImages
        fields = ['image_file']
        widget = forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True})
```

View to handle multiple images

```
def upload_product_images(request):
    form = ProductImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    files = requests.FILES.getlist['image_file']
    title = request.POST['product_title']
    description = request.POST['descritpion']
    product = Product(product_title=title,product_description=description)
    product.save()
    # You would have to make some iterations through the list images in order topost 
    # them to your database
    if form.is_valid:
       for file in files:
           prod_image_data = ProductImages(product=product, image=file)
           prod_image_data.save() 
    return redirect(# redirect to anywhere you)
```